# What's the scope of a CoroutineScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am currently learning about coroutines. In `onCreate` of my `Application` class I did the following:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    val job = CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        while(true) {
            Timber.i("hello from coroutine")
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    job.invokeOnCompletion {
        Timber.i("job.invokeOnCompletion")
    }
}
```

I would have expected the job to be canceled once `onCreate` is finished, but instead it runs endlessly:

```
2020-06-28 16:23:11.436 onCreate$job: hello from coroutine
[..]
2020-06-28 16:23:19.489 onCreate$job: hello from coroutine
2020-06-28 16:23:21.504 onCreate$job: hello from coroutine
2020-06-28 16:23:22.512 onCreate$job: hello from coroutine
2020-06-28 16:23:23.516 onCreate$job: hello from coroutine
[..]
2020-06-28 16:23:45.671 onCreate$job: hello from coroutine
```

1. So what is the scope of `CoroutineScope`? Shouldn't it be canceled as soon as the end of `onCreate` is reached?
2. Notice the job output, there's a gap between *16:23:**19**.489* and *16:23:**21**.504*, missing *16:23:**20***. Can anyone explain why?
3. I forced a garbage collection multiple times, still the output continues. Would have expected the `job`to be garbage collected as it is a local variable?

Comment: Until it's canceled. You created your own that is not canceled by you, and therefore it has no idea about your intention to cancel it in onDestroy. You can use `lifecycleScope` instead that handles this for you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be garbage collected, as `job` is a local variable?

Comment: is a `CoroutineScope` just a group of coroutines? The scope is nothing like a local variable scope?

Answer (score 0):

A thread can't be garbage collected if it's still running.

The coroutine is still running and it won't be canceled when the onCreate() ends. You can attach a coroutine to a lifecycle of a fragment or activity if you want to be canceled automatically when the fragment is destroyed. But, onCreate() and functions in general don't have a lifecycle. If you want to achieve something similar, you have to have `job.cancel()` at the end of your function.

So to answer your questions:

1. No, threads (or coroutines) don't get canceled arbitrarily.
2. CPU was busy running other tasks for 1 sec. IO threads don't have the same priority as UI for example.
3. You can't force GC, you can only make a suggestion that this is a good time to collect garbages. You shouldn't try to outsmart the GC. Also, there was nothing to be collected.