# Is a coroutine finished when its job/scope gets garbage collected?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Am I leaking resources by doing something like this

```kotlin
class Foo {

   private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main.immediate + supervisorJob)

   init {
       scope.launch {
             // perform work
       }
   }
}
```

Will the garbage collector somehow stop my coroutine if/when `Foo` and its scope/job get collected?

Comment: There are a bunch of questions/answers in SO related to coroutine scopes vs regular execution scopes. They all seem to say that coroutine scopes aren't effected by references to them going out of execution scope.  Here's one such question that it seems might apply to your situation:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623946/whats-the-scope-of-a-coroutinescope

Comment: I was kindof hopping that wasn't the case. Thank you for pointing me to that SO question